# Cant use single DVI monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, amd-graphics, dvi

Ubuntu 17 with DVI cable connecting to TV. Doesn't show picture when booting.

Added second screen with HDMI and now both work. I can disable the HDMI screen and only use the DVI like intended. When I pull the HDMI cable BOTH screens are gone..

WTH ubuntu!

AMD R9 390 graphicscard on ubuntu 17. Don't even know where to start.. The ubuntu display settings are completely lacking, AMD drivers are bugged on ubuntu.. Should I just switch to a different distro?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by upgrading to 18.04. Luckily the upgrade succeeded.

Really had a horrible time with 17.10 most buggy build so far..